# Webservice for dynamic lists with dynamic columns

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I need list functionality much like the one found in SharePoint (and Dynamics CRM) where I can extend the database (either programatically or from a webpage) and a new WSDL+webservice is generated for the service.

Simplified scenario:
Create list "Shoppinglist", add column "Quantity", add column "Description". I should now be able to add a webervice reference to this list from Visual Studio and use it as if it was a hardcoded webservice for shoppinglist.

Any pointers on where to start? Does it exist already? I'd preffer if it was slightly more mobile than SharePoint. (Yes Microsoft; sometimes we do the unthinkable and migrate content.)

Answer (score 0):

Using [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx) and [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx) you can easily publish a CRUD interface for a database. This can also be done using [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd728275).

Comment: Correct. Great stuff. :) My question however is on the dynamic generation of web services. To serve web services that have different entities and the entities have different properties/attributes than when it was originally written by the developer. Dynamically creating new services with new entities.

Comment: @TeddHansen I don't know whether an automated solution exists, nor whether it will be secure and maintainable. You'll still need clients to consume the service, right? How will they know the service now publishes new entities or fields, or worse, a field definition has been altered? But perhaps you could automate the Entity Framework EDMX generation.

Comment: This is essentially the same solution as provided by both SharePoint and Dynamics CRM. There is no doubt it is secure, highly maintainable and preferred in many situations. I'm coding against such API's every day and find it very satisfying compared to old-school unmanaged access to new objects/fields.